# Passing a JavaScript string to a <div id="div1"> tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a code where i use a while loop to generate the SVG images with little variations representing the charts.

I want to show them on a webpage inside `<div>` tags.

I wanted to know that how can I pass the value of a string to this particular HTML tag  `<div id="div1"></div>`

Comment: You are missing your code

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if one of them helped.

Answer (score 1):

Add and delete existing content within the div:

```
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "String!";
```

Add and keep existing content within the div:

```
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML + = "String!";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery you can use `$('#div1').html(youstring);`

If you use plain javascript, you can use `document.getElementById('div1').innerHtml = yourstring`

Answer (score 0):

By getting the element by it's `id` with `document.getElementById()` and then use `.innerHTML` to set the HTML of that element:

```
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = stringValueHere;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the inner text for the div:

```
var mystring = "hello"; 
document.getElementById('div1').innerText = mystring;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta use javascript for this. This is what you should do:

```
document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML="foo";
```